# Sample letter styled Latex Template (with some specification) for word document

Tags: latex, pdflatex, biblatex

I want to prepare a manuscript in "**Word on a letter-sized paper with no line numbering, a line spacing of 1.5, Times New Roman 11-point font size, margins top/bottom of 1”, margins left/right of 1.25.**” But I am comfortable with Latex. So, Is there any possibility to prepare the manuscript in latex for the above mentioned style(format), then can convert to word file. If means guide me with Latex template for the above style settings.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}


This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: @user1999109 Note that the font is still Computer Modern and not Times New Roman. See here if you really need that font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67768/times-new-roman-font